# Get content from Open Office document

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-writer

How can I get text from Open Office document?

I use OO to convert ms word and excel files to PDF format in order to display in a web page. But in some cases,  it is possible to face corrupted files, and corrupted files opens as very big xml.

To solve this problem I am going to get first row of content, and if xml tag exists suggest to user download document and try repair or open it in ms word. But I didn't find any detailed documentation and examples how to work with text.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code that you are using to interact with OpenOffice?

Answer (score 0):

From the tag, I assume you are looking for information using C#.  There are not many examples, but have a look at [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section 24.1.  The example inserts text into a writer document.

One way to read text is to create a cursor, select the first line, and then get the value by calling `oCursor.getString()`.  [This page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/Text_cursor) shows example commands in Basic which you can adapt to C#.